# node.js randomly becomes unresponsive

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I have a simple node.js app that uses express. There are clients that connect to it. I have windows 10 too. What I find is that, usually, the node.js terminal seems to get hanged, and stop listening. But the crazy part is that, when I resize the terminal window (like clicking and dragging the corner to resize it), it becomes responsive again and starts logging everything that got queued.

Does anyone know what's going on and know how to fix it?

This is another person having probably the same issue
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8196

Thanks

Comment: What nodejs version you are using ? Is it normaal console or Powershell command line ?

Comment: Normal one, but that last comment in that link seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: Cool, glad that worked :)